# Floating an element but still keeping it within its parent specified padding

Tags: css

How can I `float` an element within a `<figure>` tag, without the text going outside the padded `listing-area` figure div itself?

---

I am looking to achieve the desired style:

[image: desired style on another website]

And when even more content is added within the `div` it adopts the `padding-top` and `padding-bottom`.

See:

[image: div adopting the padding with more content]

*[gemfields.com](https://gemfields.com/)*

At present, *my* CSS does not obey the `padding-top` and `padding-bottom`.

What I do not understand is that I do have a `group:after` which clears the float, usually (and I did just assume) it would allow the content to wrap if you like at the bottom of the floated div, clearing it, but this is not the case for me this time.

---

My CSS:

```
#listing {
    display: block  
}
#listing .listing-area {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 140px 0;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: 0  
}
#listing .listing-area.right-listing {
    text-align: right   
}
#listing .listing-area::after {
    content:" ";
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, hsla(0,0%,100%,0) 0%, hsla(0,0%,100%,1) 68%, hsla(0,0%,100%,1) 100%);
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 0
}
#listing figcaption {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1
}
.row-four-col {
    width: 40%
}
.fr {
    float: right
}
.group:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
    height: -1px
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="listing">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="row-full-col row-space">
      <figure class="listing-area right-listing" style="background-image:url('https://static.pexels.com/photos/541522/pexels-photo-541522.jpeg')">
        <figcaption class="content-wrapper">
          <div class="row-four-col fr group">
            <h2>Personal Executive Coaching</h2>
            <p>Non Directive 1:1 executive coaching programmes for senior level executives. These extend typically over a minimum of 9 months and are provided by a combination of face to face meetings and, if required telephone sessions. They are personal and confidential and information is not shared with the employing organization.They provide the opportunity of personal support to executives who often find themselves relatively isolated in their role without the right opportunity to discuss personal or business concerns and review their options.</p>
            <p>Business leaders spend their time effectively ‘on stage’ in their role. Tailored coaching support provides a ‘safe rehearsal’ environment to reveal and resolve problems and dilemmas that we all from time to time face. The process facilitates such leaders to arrive at their best judgements or decisions. It does not presume to provide solutions.</p>
          </div>
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

## jsFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/LwLs839g/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear the floatting element :

see: https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

> **The Overflow Method** relies on setting the overflow CSS property on a parent element. If this property is set to auto or hidden on the parent element, the parent will expand to contain the floats, effectively clearing it for succeeding elements. This method can be beautifully semantic as it may not require an additional elements. However if you find yourself adding a new div just to apply this, it is equally as non-semantic as the empty div method and less adaptable. Also bear in mind that the overflow property isn't specifically for clearing floats. Be careful not to hide content or trigger unwanted scrollbars.

```
#listing .listing-area {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 140px 0;
  margin: 0;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: 0  ;
  overflow:hidden/* clear floats*/
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/LwLs839g/5/

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

#listing {
  display: block
}

.row-full-col {
  width: 100%
}

.row-four-col {
  width: 40%
}

.fr {
  float: right
}

.group:after {
  content: " ";
  clear: both;
  line-height: 0;
  display: table
}

.content-wrapper {
  max-width: 1440px;
  margin: 0px auto
}

#listing .listing-area {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 140px 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: 0;
  overflow: hidden
}

#listing .listing-area.right-listing {
  text-align: right
}

#listing .listing-area::after {
  content: " ";
  background: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0) 0%, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 1) 68%, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right top, color-stop(0%, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0)), color-stop(68%, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 1)), color-stop(100%, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 1)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0) 0%, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 1) 68%, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0) 0%, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 1) 68%, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 1) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0) 0%, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 1) 68%, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0) 0%, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 1) 68%, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ffffff', GradientType=1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 0
}

#listing figcaption {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1
}
```

```html
<div id="listing">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="row-full-col row-space">
      <figure class="listing-area right-listing" style="background-image:url('https://static.pexels.com/photos/541522/pexels-photo-541522.jpeg')">
        <figcaption class="content-wrapper">
          <div class="row-four-col fr group">
            <h2>Personal Executive Coaching</h2>
            <p>Non Directive 1:1 executive coaching programmes for senior level executives. These extend typically over a minimum of 9 months and are provided by a combination of face to face meetings and, if required telephone sessions. They are personal
              and confidential and information is not shared with the employing organization.They provide the opportunity of personal support to executives who often find themselves relatively isolated in their role without the right opportunity to discuss
              personal or business concerns and review their options.</p>
            <p>Business leaders spend their time effectively ‘on stage’ in their role. Tailored coaching support provides a ‘safe rehearsal’ environment to reveal and resolve problems and dilemmas that we all from time to time face. The process facilitates
              such leaders to arrive at their best judgements or decisions. It does not presume to provide solutions.</p>
          </div>
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```